# Representing time sequence input/output in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've been working through the TensorFlow documentation (still learning), and I can't figure out how to represent input/output sequence data.  My inputs are a sequences of 20 8-entry vectors, making a 8x20xN matrix, where N is the number of instances.  I'd like to eventually pass these through an LSTM for sequence to sequence learning.  I know I need a 3D vector, but I'm unsure which dimensions are which.

RTFMs with pointers to the correct documentation greatly appreciated.  I feel like this is obvious and I'm just missing it.

Comment: For what its worth, the following link, combined with @Torkoal 's link below, got me the closest to answering this before I switched to using Keras as a frontend: https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/notebooks/3_NeuralNetworks/recurrent_network.ipynb

Answer (score 1):

As described in the excellent blog post by [WildML](http://www.wildml.com/2016/08/rnns-in-tensorflow-a-practical-guide-and-undocumented-features/), the proper way is to save your example in a TFRecord using the formate `tf.SequenceExample()`. Using TFRecords for this provides the following advantages:

- You can split your data in to many files and load them each on a different GPU.
- You can use Tensorflow utilities for loading the data (for example using `Queues` to load you data on demand.
- Your model code will be separate from your dataset processing (this is a good habit to have).
- You can bring new data to your model just by putting it into this format.

TFRecords uses `protobuf` or protocol buffers as a way to format your data. The documentation of which can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/). The basic idea is you have a format for your data (in this case in the format of tf.SequenceExample) save it to a TFRecord and load it using the same data definition. Code for this pattern can be found at [this](https://github.com/dennybritz/tf-rnn/blob/master/sequence_example.ipynb) ipython notebook.

As my answer is mostly summarizing the WildML blog post on this topic, I suggest you check that out, again found [here](http://www.wildml.com/2016/08/rnns-in-tensorflow-a-practical-guide-and-undocumented-features/).

Comment: Thank you for the pointer, and the tutorial was helpful. However, it didn't really help me solve the problem.  Also, adding in TFRecords makes sense when dealing with big data, but in my case I'm more interested in how the network works, not in massive data sets.. the TFRecords abstraction just seems like added complexity for my needs. 

In the end, I wound up using tensorflow through the keras frontend, which takes numpy arrays of (batch_size, seqlen, input_vec).  Keras is a bit tempermental in other ways, but it works.